# Display Local Images in Django App

Tags: html, django, image, templates

Is it possible to display images that are stored locally on a django app? I am currently building a workflow that integrates with a web service, and I have dynamically analyzed data that the user uploads which is then processed locally and saved locally (ie, not in the static directories). I am currently just trying to build something minimally viable before making it "formally correct" (I know I'm supposed to store the images I want displayed in the static directory, but as they aren't static, this doesn't make much sense to me since users can upload and delete their processed data so it's not always necessarily going to be there; the workflow is presently external the web service so integrating them is something I'm hoping to get to after having a product working since the integration itself will probably take several months and I need something minimally working before that for a demo). I have the images I want to display stored locally (they are created during the workflow after the user uploads their data), and when generating templated HTML's the paths I expect are actually showing up (ie, when browsing and viewing the HTML, the path that is shown is the path the images are locally on my computer) however, Django passes the following error:

```
Not Found: /local/path/to/analysis/analysisdirs/img.png
```

When I try to open the images locally, they show up just fine (so they actually exist). Is there a way to dynamically add images such that django can find them only for the particular rendering that is being displayed (ie, it adds them temporarily to the static path once a batch of files are analyzed, and then removes them if this batch of files is deleted)?

When I go to the page that should show an image, there is just a blank space for the image with the alt text, and when I look at the html, it shows:

```
<img src="/local/path/to/analysis/analysis_dirs/img.png" alt="My Image" height="600" width="700">
```

Which is exactly what I was expecting, but apparently is wrong.

I have the following in my settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/local/'

# the directory to place all uploaded graphs and outputs
SERVER_DIR = "/local/"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(SERVER_DIR, 'input_data')
MEDIA_URL = os.path.join(SERVER_DIR, 'input_data/')

OUTPUT_DIR = os.path.join(SERVER_DIR, 'path/')
DATA_FOLDER = os.path.join(SERVER_DIR, "path")
```

which I was hoping would do the job, but alas it does not :(

So what I am hoping for is that when I call:

```
context = {'img': '/local/path/to/analysis/analysis_dirs/img.png'}
render(request, 'myapp/mytemplate.html', context)
```

Where template.html has:

```
<img src="{{ img }}" alt="My Image" height="600" width="700">
```

I would be able to do something like:

```
static_media_path += '/local/path/to/analysis/'
```

when the particular analysis is run, and then when a particular analysis is deleted:

```
static_media_path -= '/local/path/to/analysis/'
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are developing on your local machine in debug mode, did you add

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.static import serve

#at the end of file
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^/local/path/to/analysis/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
    ]
```

to your apps urls.py